# Ocultar un campo en Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo un formulario, pero este tendrá cierta información ya llenada, y esos campos quiero ocultarlos para poder mandar esos parámetros, pero al momento de poner los parámetros no se comportan como esperaba.
este es mi forms.py

```
class EscuelasForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Escuelas
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(
                attrs={
                    'readonly':True,
                    'hidden': True,
                    'placeholder': 'hola',
                    'required': False
                })}
```

Como pueden ver tengo el campo de hidden : true, pero el el template aun aparece el nombre:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de ocultar ese campo?

Por si hace falta dejo mi views.py

```
def agregarEscuela(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        escuelasForm = EscuelasForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if escuelasForm.is_valid():
            escuelasForm.save()
            return redirect('adminEscuelas')
    else:
        escuelasForm = EscuelasForm()
    return render(request, 'administracion/agregar_escuela.html',
                  {'escuelasForm': escuelasForm})
```

Anexo mi template;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nueva persona</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Agregar escuela</h1>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        {{escuelasForm}}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'adminEscuelas' nivel%}">Regresar al inicio pa</a>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor comparte tu template, lo mas probable es que el error se encuentre ahi.

Comment: Listo, actualice la publicación, agradezco el tiempo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que reemplazar el EmailInput por HiddenInput te ayudaría:

```
class EscuelasForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Escuelas
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'email': HiddenInput(
                attrs={
                    'required': False
                })}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probare!

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto la solución que te propongo, el problema sucede ya que estas incrustando directamente el template tag sin indicarle como renderizarlo, solo lo estas colocando así: {{ escuelasForm }}

Si no quieres tener control sobre el renderizado del formulario lo tendrias que hacer de esta manera:

```
{{ escuelasForm.as_p }}
{{ escuelasForm.as_table }}
{{ escuelasForm.as_ul }}
```

as_p renderizara tus label e inputs dentro de un p, as_table, renderizara cada label e input dentro de un tr y as_ul renderizara los campos dentro de elementos li.

Usando uno de estos ya no deberías de tener problemas, ya debería de ocultar los campos hidden y su label.

También si estas usando una versión de Django mayor o igual a 2.1 puedes indicar que no quieres un label de esta manera:

```
class EscuelasForm(ModelForm):

  email = forms.EmailField(label=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Escuelas
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(
                attrs={
                    'readonly':True,
                    'hidden': True,
                    'placeholder': 'hola',
                    'required': False
                })}
```

Y la ultima opción es que renderices de manera manual todo el form, de esta manera tendrás un mayor control de como se muestra el form, te comparto un ejemplo con bootstrap 4:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'mi_url' %}">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for hidden in escuelasForm.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if escuelasForm.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 alert alert-danger">
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="row">
        {% for field in escuelasForm.visible_fields %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group form-group-{{ field.name }}"
                     {% if field.field.style %}style="{{ field.field.style }}"{% endif %}>
                    <label for="{% if field.errors %}inputError{% else %}{{ field.id_for_label }}{% endif %}"
                           class="control-label {% if field.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}">
                        {{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}
                    </label>

                    {{ field }}
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                        <small id="{{ field.name }}HelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
                            {{ field.help_text }}
                        </small>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</span>
                    {% endif %}

                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</form>
```

Donde dice escuelasForm.hidden_fields se encarga de insertar los campos ocultos, solo el campo, sin label. Y donde dice escuelasForm.visible_fields se encarga de mostrar los campos visibles con su label y otras cosas como help_text, errores, etc.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Agradezco el comentario!, lo probare para verificar, muchas gracias!